# Apache 403 Error WampServer 2

Tags: apache, configuration, webserver, alias, http-status-code-403

I have WampServer 2 installed and I have created an alias on my computer called test which points to directory g:/test/.

However I keep getting a 403 error when I try and access localhost/test/

Which is being caused by these lines in my httpd.conf (if I comment these lines out it loads)

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

My conf for test is as follows:

```
Alias /test/ "g:/test/" 
<Directory "g:/test/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

How do I override the Require all denied in my test.conf file to stop the 403 errors?

Error Log reads:
[Sun Dec 09 18:51:23.757803 2012] [authz_core:error] [pid 5128:tid 884] [client ::1:50622] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: G:/test/

Access Log reads:
::1 - - [09/Dec/2012:18:51:23 +0000] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 403 207

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace deprecated:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

By:

```
Require all granted
```

Concerns only [Apache >= 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html). However, I recommand to disable mod_access_compat (line LoadModule) to avoid Order/Allow/Deny conflicts with Require.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I will accept this answer once it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Allow from all
  
    #Require local
    Require all granted

above file comment #Require local
add extra **Require all granted**

solved